# Creating dynamic attributes and properties in model class

Tags: sql, dynamic, yii, model

I used code

```
$sql="SELECT 'Name' FROM XXX";
$names =$connection->createCommand($sql)->query()->readAll();

$myDynamicObject = new DynamicModel($names);
```

---

```
class DynamicModel extends CModel
{
    protected $_members = array();


    public function __construct($nameFields)
    {
        foreach ($nameFields as $member) {
            $this->_members[$member] = null;
        }

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $allMembers = implode(', ', array_keys($this->_members));
        return array(
            array($allMembers, 'required'),
        );
    }

    public function __get($attribute)
    {

        if (in_array($attribute, array_keys($this->_members))) {
            return $this->_members[$attribute];
        } else {
            return parent::__get($attribute);
        }
    }

    public function __set($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($attribute, array_keys($this->_members))) {
            return $this->_members[$attribute] = $value;
        } else {
            return parent::__set($attribute, $value);
        }
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->_members;
    }

    public function setAttributes($attributes)
    {
        $this->_members = $attributes;
    }

}
```

i print this model in controller but
not nothing coming..server error came..

" More
An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
Error code: 500"

Answer (score 0):

`CModel` is an abstract class and you need to at least implement the `attributeNames()` function.
In your case I guess the following should suffice:

```
public function attributeNames()
{
    return array_keys($this->_members);
}
```